# Javascript require() a file in tests several times does not create the object again

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, require

I am writing some tests for a javascript API with mocha. I docker up my project before running the tests and I have realized that requiring a file to create an object in several tests, for example like these ones:

```
    it('should return false 1', () =>  {
      const testObject = require(./file.json)
      delete testObject.neededAttribute1;
      expect(function(testObject)).to.be.false;
    });

    it('should return false 2', () =>  {
      const testObject = require(./file.json)
      delete testObject.neededAttribute2;
      expect(function(testObject)).to.be.false;
    });
```

Javascript won't create the object `testObject` in the second test, but use the first one with the changes previously made, making my tests unusable if I don't manually restore the object with whatever I have changed after the test has been executed.

I understand Javascript does this to be more efficient not loading the same file all the time, but just once.

But how can I make my tests in which I have a file with a correct object and I want to introduce small modifications one by one in each test?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clone the object.

Import your object in a before function

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/mocha-global-setup-and-teardown-before-after

Then in each function or in beforeEach function, clone that object with something like lodash's cloneDeep function.

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution, even if more verbose, but it avoids cloning the object before each test because maybe is not necessary.

```
describe('Tests', () => {

  const baseTestObject = require('./file.json');

  it('should return false 1', () =>  {
    const testObject = Object.assign({}, baseTestObject, { attribute1: null });
    expect(function(testObject)).to.be.false;
  });

  it('should return false 2', () =>  {
    const testObject = Object.assign({}, baseTestObject, { attribute2: null });
    expect(function(testObject)).to.be.false;
  });
```

Merging and cloning the objects the following way

```
const testObject = Object.assign({}, baseTestObject, { attribute2: null });
```

Maintains the original testObject therefore not affecting other tests.